# how to manage npm if accidentially deleted package.json file from the directory?

Tags: npm

I started learning node package manager but eventually deleted my package json file from then till now i am unable to solve the issue of workspace[image]

The log file data is ---->
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share the log information in 2022-02-06T09....debug-0.log

Comment: @BalajiSivasakthi please check again i have added info of log file

Comment: try this npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for responding
In my case i has to go to npmrc file and clear cache there.